# How to write a math closure with subscript in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

Currently I'm writing closures with a bar, e.g. `\bar{\Omega}`. Maybe there's a better way,
but it looks more or less OK.

The problems start when I want to define e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\cellFluid}{Y}
\newcommand{\cellSolid}{\cellFluid_0}
```

Now `\bar{\cellSolid}` looks very ugly, and I have to use `\bar{\cellFluid}_0` which
defeats the point of defining `\cellSolid` and makes the code hard to read.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's not strictly correct (in LaTeX syntax), but `\bar\cellSolid` will only put the bar on the Y, not the Y with subscript.

Comment: The bar is still shifted by a bit.

Comment: Does `$\overline{\cellSolid}$` produce the desired result?

Comment: No, the `\overline` extends over the index as well. And even on its own, it's much wider
than `\bar`, so it looks wrong.

Comment: I usually use `\overline` for closures, `\bar` being too short.  If a set is called `Y_0` I would want the line to go over the whole symbol pair, to distinguish from a "`0` opertaion" on the closure.  Thus I think Jubobs suggestion is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Your implicit expectation that it is possible to uniformly typeset the
closure of any piece of formula results from mistaking TeX for a
markup system while it is a typesetting system.  Often enough, you can
ignore the distinction between these two concepts, which is made
especially blurry by LaTeX. But when it comes to typesetting maths, it
is not possible to assume that both concepts are the same (see how
MathML distinguishes presentation and semantics).

To solve your problem, add near the definition of `\cellFluid` a new
definition for a macro `\cellFluidBar` typesetting the closure of
`\cellFluid`.

Alternatively you can look for alternative notations for the closure,
such as $\mathop{\mathrm{Adh}}_X Y_0$, that are cumbersome but smooth
that edge between markup and typesetting.

If you enjoy programming TeX, you can devise a `\closure` macro taking
a unique argument and typestting its closure in a generic way but
supports a dictionary of exceptions. Aside from fun, there is probably
very little benefits over the first, easy and straightforward,
solution.

Comment: With `amsmath`, `\operatorname{Adh}` is easier than `\mathop{\mathrm{Adh}}` and `\DeclareMathOperator{\Adh}{Adh}` with `\Adh` in the text is even easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to the problem. It does the job to the letter, but
`\closure{poreSkeleton}` is used instead of the more elegant `\closure{\poreSkeleton}`.
If anyone knows of a package that provides a similar functionality, or possible problems
with this approach, please let me know.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% ———begin setup———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
\makeatletter
\newcommand\constructor[2]{
  \expandafter\newcommandx\csname #1\endcsname[1][1=]{\ifstrequal{##1}{}
    {#2}
    {\@ifundefined{#1@##1}
      {\errmessage{"#1" has no field named "##1"}}
      {\@nameuse{#1@##1}}
    }
  }
  \@namedef{#1@self}{#2}
}
\newcommand\set[3]{             % this, field, value
  \@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}
}
\newcommand\newcommandWithIndex[3]{
  \constructor{#1}{#2#3}
  \set{#1}{body}{#2}
  \set{#1}{index}{#3}
}
\newcommand{\closure}[1]{
  \@ifundefined{#1@body}
  {\bar{#1}}
  {\bar{\@nameuse{#1@body}}\@nameuse{#1@index}}
}
\makeatother
% ———end setup—————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

\newcommandWithIndex{poreSkeleton}{\Omega}{_0^\varepsilon}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Plain:          & $\poreSkeleton$          $\Omega_0^\varepsilon$\\
  Messy closure:  & $\bar{\poreSkeleton}$    $\bar{\Omega_0^\varepsilon}$\\
  Proper closure: & $\closure{poreSkeleton}$ $\bar{\Omega}_0^\varepsilon$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can define a `toksloadcsident` macro like this `\def\toksloadcsident#1\to#2{\edef\toksload@a{\expandafter\ignore\string#1}#2=\expandafter{\toksload@a}}` that loads token register `#2` with the identifiant of the macro `#1` (without the `\\`).  To check if a token is a macro you can use `\ifcat`.  You may look up for `\toksloadcs` and `\testcs` in my TeX format _Bhrìd Tex_. http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/bhrid/trunk/src/kernel.nw?view=markup