# Overline over a symbol with an index

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols, typography, subscripts

For example, if I want to write a closure of a set, which is denoted `A_1`, should I use `$\overline{A_1}$` or `$\overline A_1$` (or something completely different)?

For me, the more logical choice seems to be `$\overline{A_1}$` (since I read `\overline` command as "closure of"). But maybe from typographical point of view this can be considered differently.

---

Here is a [MathB.in link](http://mathb.in/23832) for comparison. (I am aware that rendering in MathJax and LaTeX is not necessarily the same, but I do not know what is standard way to make images with symbols for TeX.SE posts.)

Here is also a picture which I tried to create from pdf output using the method described in [this answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1799/how-do-you-crop-an-attached-pdf/1802#1802) on meta.

[image: $\overline{A_1}$ vs. $\overline A_1$]

---

I have seen that there exists a question [\overline and \widehat with subscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151095/overline-and-widehat-with-subscript). But that question asks about subscript added to the bar symbol, not subscript added to the symbol(s) which are under the bar.

Comment: This question seems to be somewhat related: [Forcing \overline not to continuously extend to adjacent variables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188416/forcing-overline-not-to-continuously-extend-to-adjacent-variables). And also this: [How to write a math closure with subscript in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137090/how-to-write-a-math-closure-with-subscript-in-latex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly something like `$\overline{A_1}$`, because it is closure of `$A_1$`. But I understand, that the rule may look a bit too long for you. Indeed, there is no italic correction for math font. If you prefer a bit shorter version, see, e.g. answers to [Appearance issues with \bar{} and \underline{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/143037/appearance-issues-with-bar-and-underline/143041#143041).

Answer (score 1):

You could think of `${\overline A}_1$` as being defined as `$\overline{A_1}$` in which case you have the shorter line and can just write `\overline A_1`.